# css style for a button-like <div>

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying add  in my project to simulate a popup window (where later I will add content from others pages from my application). I have the follow code:

**html**

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="title">Titulo <span id="button">X</span> </div>
    <div id="text">Conteudo</div>
</div>
```

**javascript/jquery**

```
$('window').load(function(){
    $('#box').draggable();
});
```

**css**

```
#box {
    box-sizing: padding-box;
    box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px black;
    border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
    width: 320px;
    height: 640px;
    min-width: 160px;
    min-height: 500px;
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 750px;
    top: 200px;
    left: 200px;
}

#button {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 95%;
    min-width: 32px;
    max-width: 5%;
    position:absolute;
}

#title {
    background-color: black;
    text-decoration-color: white;
    font: 32px/36px arial;
    position: relative;
}

#text {
    background-color: white;
    text-decoration-color: black;
    font: 24px/28px sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}
```

Bottom line: I want the element identified by id=button stay in the right corner of the title bar from my  "window", but in this current state, that's what i got:

[image]

how i can improve this to achieve what i want?

ps.: i accept suggestion using jquery / jquery-ui. I try earlier BootstrapDialog, but don't serve for my project because dont't ajust itself according to loaded content and block the other contents from my page when it's open.

Comment: check this out http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/html-5-drag-drop-basics.html#fbid=-rnTJ0wlBFh

Comment: Draggable is a feature of **jQuery UI** - have you included that library?

Comment: I just did. Now it's working fine, and I am concentrated in the css of the button I have mentioned.

Comment: Since you're already using jQuery UI - why don't you just use jQuery dialog for this? It'll give you a very easy to use dialog which is draggable. Also it looks like you're using Bootstrap, they also have build in dialogs. Otherwise, I suggest you edit your question and remove all the draggable stuff leaving the CSS problem.

Comment: ok, i change the question to leave only the css problem. In relation to your answer, i try use bootstrap, but the options i found aren't useful to me (i explain in the question). I accept sugestions usinf jquery or jquery-ui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got what you wanted. The padding was a bit much so I removed it. Also if you want it aligned right when position is absolute you just need right:0px; Another thing the 'X' was not aligned center in the div so I added text-align:center; Change your #button css style to the following:

```
    #button {
             background-color: red;
             min-width: 32px;
             max-width: 5%;
             position:absolute;
             right:0px;
             text-align:center;
             padding-left:10px;
             padding-right:10px;
    }
```

Comment: Next time @BrandonBoone